# Is it possible to construct drop-down parameter values in Jenkins while the Job is Running?

Tags: jenkins, parameters, jenkins-plugins

Please let me know if & how is it possible to achieve this in Jenkins.

I have a drop down (say drop-down1 ) with two values

```
Australia
Poland
```

-> If the user selects Australia the next drop down parameter (say drop-down2 ) should show values

```
Cricket
Rugby
```

and if he selects Poland the values should be

```
Soccer 
Rugby
```

-> Finally if the user selected Australia & Rugby then the third drop down (say drop-down3 ) should show

```
Year1999
Year2003
```

& if the user selected Poland & Rugby then the third drop down (say drop-down3 ) should show

```
Year2001
Year2005
Year2009
```

Likewise if he select Australia and Cricket the third drop down should show some other values.

Is this possible to achieve in Jenkins ? if so, how? Please suggest.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You probably want to explore one of the choice plugins. Check:

[Extensible Choice](https://wiki.jenkins.io/plugins/servlet/mobile?contentId=65669637#content/view/65669637)

[Extended Choice](https://wiki.jenkins.io/plugins/servlet/mobile?contentId=46334385#content/view/46334385)

[Dynamic Extended Choice](https://plugins.jenkins.io/dynamic_extended_choice_parameter)

Take head, the "Extended" ones  are very old and may have vulnerabilities or constrained functionality.

Search https://plugins.jenkins.io/ for `choice` or `Parameter` for more options. Eg:
[Active Choices](https://wiki.jenkins.io/plugins/servlet/mobile?contentId=74875908).